# Tcl configure -background of button fails

Tags: button, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have the following proc which changes the select file button colour depending on if the current path in the entrybox exists or not. The first if loop works, for the second I get "invalid command name ""  while executing "$Button configure -background  red"   And I don't have a clue why...

```
proc ::CheckGUIPaths {  } {

set FilePathList [list $::GUI_DB_path $::GUI_BDF_path $::GUI_ALLOW_path $::GUI_EXCEL_path $::GUI_HM_path]
set Buttons [list .dsm.nb.f1.btn_DBfile .dsm.nb.f1.btn_BDFfile .dsm.nb.f1.btn_ALLOWfile .dsm.nb.f1.btn_HMfile .dsm.nb.f1.btn_XLfile]

for { set n 0 } { $n <= 5 } { incr n }  {

   set Path [lindex $FilePathList $n]
   set Button [lindex $Buttons $n]

   if { [ file exists $Path ] == 1 } {  
        $Button configure -background  green 
      }      
   if { [ file exists $Path ] == 0 } {  
        $Button configure -background  red
      }   
   }
return 0

}
```

Comment: What kind of buttons are these? Are they [button](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/button.htm)s or [ttk::button](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_button.htm)s?

Comment: just simple buttons, not ttk::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have 5 elements in those lists, but your loop iterates 6 times. You probably want `{$n < 5}` or `{$n < [llength $FilePathList]}`

---

A note about style/efficiency: You don't need to test the existance twice

```
if {[ file exists $Path ]} {  
    $Button configure -background  green 
} else {  
    $Button configure -background  red
}
```

or

```
$Button configure -background [expr {[ file exists $Path ] ? "green" : "red"}]
```

Comment: For increased hack-power, `[lindex {red green} [file exists $Path]]`

Comment: @Donal, +1 for nastiness and -1 for obfuscation!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to replace the loop with this construct:

```
foreach Path $FilePathList Button $Buttons {
    if {[file exists $Path]} {
        $Button configure -background green
    } else {
        $Button configure -background green
    }
}
```

Writing it this way means you don't need to keep track of the number of items.  However, if any of the lists should ever have more items than the other, the other iteration variable will get empty values to match.